# Return the first letter of every word in a string using java-script in minimum code

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

0

I want to get the first letter of every word in a string from the array. The below is the code I am using.

```
[
  {name: "Joe John", age: 22},
  {name: "Kevin Parker", age: 24},
  {name: "Peter Keller", age: 21}
].map(e => e.name.match(/\b(\w)/g)).join(",");
```

The expected result: JJ,KP,PK

Can anybody help me?

Comment: That code snippet looks pretty succinct to me, what's the issue with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
[
  {name: "Joe John", age: 22},
  {name: "Kevin Parker", age: 24},
  {name: "Peter Keller", age: 21}
].map(e => e.name.match(/\b(\w)/g).join("")).join(",")
```

Comment: @Christian No. It's actually "JJ,KP,PK", which is correct.

Comment: Ah, I must have modified on accident.

Answer (score 0):

```js
[
  {name: 'Joe John', age: 22},
  {name: 'Kevin Parker', age: 24},
  {name: 'Peter Keller', age: 21}
]
  .map(entry => entry.name)
  .map(name => name.split(' ').map(name => name.match(/\b(\w)/g)).join(''))
  .join(',')
```

Comment: It would help if you would add a short explanation of why your answer works.

Comment: because this test is green :) 

```
test('62890697', () => {
  const result = [
    {name: 'Joe John', age: 22},
    {name: 'Kevin Parker', age: 24},
    {name: 'Peter Keller', age: 21}
  ]
    .map(entry => entry.name)
    .map(name => name.split(' ').map(name => name.match(/\b(\w)/g)).join(''))
    .join(',')
  expect(result).toEqual('JJ,KP,PK')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `map`, `split`, `join` and `destructuring`

```js
console.log(
  [
    { name: "Joe John", age: 22 },
    { name: "Kevin Parker", age: 24 },
    { name: "Peter Keller", age: 21 },
  ]
    .map(({ name }) =>
      name
        .split(" ")
        .map(([x]) => x)
        .join("")
    )
    .join(",")
);
```